# How can I make sympy.diff print expressions use pow instead of ** for power?

Tags: sympy

I use SymPy’s `diff` to get analytical expressions for my derivatives and then I need to use them in C++. Since C++ seems to only support the `pow` function, I was wondering if there is a way to get the final expression from `sympy.diff` using the C++ `pow` notation since the latter is also supported in Python. Since the expressions for my derivatives are quite lenghty (example below), it isn’t very convenient to change the notation manually, even more considering multiple expressions.

```
2.71828182845905**(-1.0*ba**4*c8*r1**2*r2**2/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**2*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) - 1.0*c1*da*r12/(da*r12 + 1.0) - 1.0*c2*da**2*r12**2/(da*r12 + 1.0)**2 - 1.0*c4*da**4*r12**4/(da*r12 + 1.0)**4 - 1.0*c4*da**3*r12**3/(da*r12 + 1.0)**3 - 1.0*c5*(ba**2*r1**2/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**2 + ba**2*r2**2/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) - 1.0*c6*(ba**3*r1**3/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**3 + ba**3*r2**3/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3) - 1.0*c7*(ba**4*r1**4/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**4 + ba**4*r2**4/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**4) - 1.0*c9*da**2*r12**2*(ba**2*r1**2/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**2 + ba**2*r2**2/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2)/(da*r12 + 1.0)**2)*2.71828182845905**(1.0*ba**4*c8*r1**2*r2**2/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**2*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) + 1.0*c1*da*r12/(da*r12 + 1.0) + 1.0*c2*da**2*r12**2/(da*r12 + 1.0)**2 + 1.0*c4*da**4*r12**4/(da*r12 + 1.0)**4 + 1.0*c4*da**3*r12**3/(da*r12 + 1.0)**3 + 1.0*c5*(ba**2*r1**2/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**2 + ba**2*r2**2/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) + 1.0*c6*(ba**3*r1**3/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**3 + ba**3*r2**3/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3) + 1.0*c7*(ba**4*r1**4/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**4 + ba**4*r2**4/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**4) + 1.0*c9*da**2*r12**2*(ba**2*r1**2/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**2 + ba**2*r2**2/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2)/(da*r12 + 1.0)**2)*(-2.0*ba**4*c8*r1**3*r2**2/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**3*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) - 2.0*ba**4*c8*r1**2*r2**3/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**2*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3) + 4.0*ba**3*c8*r1**2*r2**2/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**2*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) + 1.0*c5*(-2*ba**2*r1**3/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**3 - 2*ba**2*r2**3/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3 + 2*ba*r1**2/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**2 + 2*ba*r2**2/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) + 1.0*c6*(-3*ba**3*r1**4/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**4 - 3*ba**3*r2**4/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**4 + 3*ba**2*r1**3/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**3 + 3*ba**2*r2**3/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3) + 1.0*c7*(-4*ba**4*r1**5/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**5 - 4*ba**4*r2**5/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**5 + 4*ba**3*r1**4/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**4 + 4*ba**3*r2**4/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**4) + 1.0*c9*da**2*r12**2*(-2*ba**2*r1**3/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**3 - 2*ba**2*r2**3/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3 + 2*ba*r1**2/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**2 + 2*ba*r2**2/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2)/(da*r12 + 1.0)**2)*(2.0*ba**4*c8*r1**3*r2**2/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**3*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) + 2.0*ba**4*c8*r1**2*r2**3/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**2*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3) - 4.0*ba**3*c8*r1**2*r2**2/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**2*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) - 1.0*c5*(-2*ba**2*r1**3/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**3 - 2*ba**2*r2**3/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3 + 2*ba*r1**2/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**2 + 2*ba*r2**2/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) - 1.0*c6*(-3*ba**3*r1**4/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**4 - 3*ba**3*r2**4/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**4 + 3*ba**2*r1**3/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**3 + 3*ba**2*r2**3/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3) - 1.0*c7*(-4*ba**4*r1**5/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**5 - 4*ba**4*r2**5/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**5 + 4*ba**3*r1**4/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**4 + 4*ba**3*r2**4/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**4) - 1.0*c9*da**2*r12**2*(-2*ba**2*r1**3/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**3 - 2*ba**2*r2**3/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3 + 2*ba*r1**2/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**2 + 2*ba*r2**2/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2)/(da*r12 + 1.0)**2) + 2.71828182845905**(-1.0*ba**4*c8*r1**2*r2**2/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**2*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) - 1.0*c1*da*r12/(da*r12 + 1.0) - 1.0*c2*da**2*r12**2/(da*r12 + 1.0)**2 - 1.0*c4*da**4*r12**4/(da*r12 + 1.0)**4 - 1.0*c4*da**3*r12**3/(da*r12 + 1.0)**3 - 1.0*c5*(ba**2*r1**2/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**2 + ba**2*r2**2/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) - 1.0*c6*(ba**3*r1**3/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**3 + ba**3*r2**3/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3) - 1.0*c7*(ba**4*r1**4/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**4 + ba**4*r2**4/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**4) - 1.0*c9*da**2*r12**2*(ba**2*r1**2/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**2 + ba**2*r2**2/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2)/(da*r12 + 1.0)**2)*2.71828182845905**(1.0*ba**4*c8*r1**2*r2**2/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**2*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) + 1.0*c1*da*r12/(da*r12 + 1.0) + 1.0*c2*da**2*r12**2/(da*r12 + 1.0)**2 + 1.0*c4*da**4*r12**4/(da*r12 + 1.0)**4 + 1.0*c4*da**3*r12**3/(da*r12 + 1.0)**3 + 1.0*c5*(ba**2*r1**2/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**2 + ba**2*r2**2/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) + 1.0*c6*(ba**3*r1**3/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**3 + ba**3*r2**3/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3) + 1.0*c7*(ba**4*r1**4/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**4 + ba**4*r2**4/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**4) + 1.0*c9*da**2*r12**2*(ba**2*r1**2/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**2 + ba**2*r2**2/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2)/(da*r12 + 1.0)**2)*(16.0*(-0.5*ba**4*c8*r1**3*r2**2/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**3*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) - 0.5*ba**4*c8*r1**2*r2**3/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**2*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3) + ba**3*c8*r1**2*r2**2/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**2*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) + 0.25*c5*(-2*ba**2*r1**3/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**3 - 2*ba**2*r2**3/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3 + 2*ba*r1**2/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**2 + 2*ba*r2**2/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) + 0.25*c6*(-3*ba**3*r1**4/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**4 - 3*ba**3*r2**4/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**4 + 3*ba**2*r1**3/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**3 + 3*ba**2*r2**3/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3) + 0.25*c7*(-4*ba**4*r1**5/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**5 - 4*ba**4*r2**5/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**5 + 4*ba**3*r1**4/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**4 + 4*ba**3*r2**4/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**4) + 0.25*c9*da**2*r12**2*(-2*ba**2*r1**3/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**3 - 2*ba**2*r2**3/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3 + 2*ba*r1**2/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**2 + 2*ba*r2**2/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2)/(da*r12 + 1.0)**2)**2) + 2.71828182845905**(-1.0*ba**4*c8*r1**2*r2**2/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**2*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) - 1.0*c1*da*r12/(da*r12 + 1.0) - 1.0*c2*da**2*r12**2/(da*r12 + 1.0)**2 - 1.0*c4*da**4*r12**4/(da*r12 + 1.0)**4 - 1.0*c4*da**3*r12**3/(da*r12 + 1.0)**3 - 1.0*c5*(ba**2*r1**2/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**2 + ba**2*r2**2/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) - 1.0*c6*(ba**3*r1**3/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**3 + ba**3*r2**3/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3) - 1.0*c7*(ba**4*r1**4/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**4 + ba**4*r2**4/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**4) - 1.0*c9*da**2*r12**2*(ba**2*r1**2/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**2 + ba**2*r2**2/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2)/(da*r12 + 1.0)**2)*2.71828182845905**(1.0*ba**4*c8*r1**2*r2**2/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**2*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) + 1.0*c1*da*r12/(da*r12 + 1.0) + 1.0*c2*da**2*r12**2/(da*r12 + 1.0)**2 + 1.0*c4*da**4*r12**4/(da*r12 + 1.0)**4 + 1.0*c4*da**3*r12**3/(da*r12 + 1.0)**3 + 1.0*c5*(ba**2*r1**2/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**2 + ba**2*r2**2/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) + 1.0*c6*(ba**3*r1**3/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**3 + ba**3*r2**3/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3) + 1.0*c7*(ba**4*r1**4/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**4 + ba**4*r2**4/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**4) + 1.0*c9*da**2*r12**2*(ba**2*r1**2/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**2 + ba**2*r2**2/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2)/(da*r12 + 1.0)**2)*(6.0*ba**4*c8*r1**4*r2**2/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**4*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) + 8.0*ba**4*c8*r1**3*r2**3/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**3*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3) + 6.0*ba**4*c8*r1**2*r2**4/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**2*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**4) - 16.0*ba**3*c8*r1**3*r2**2/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**3*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) - 16.0*ba**3*c8*r1**2*r2**3/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**2*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3) + 12.0*ba**2*c8*r1**2*r2**2/((ba*r1 + 1.0)**2*(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) + 1.0*c5*(6*ba**2*r1**4/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**4 + 6*ba**2*r2**4/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**4 - 8*ba*r1**3/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**3 - 8*ba*r2**3/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3 + 2*r1**2/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**2 + 2*r2**2/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2) + 1.0*c6*(12*ba**3*r1**5/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**5 + 12*ba**3*r2**5/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**5 - 18*ba**2*r1**4/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**4 - 18*ba**2*r2**4/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**4 + 6*ba*r1**3/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**3 + 6*ba*r2**3/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3) + 1.0*c7*(20*ba**4*r1**6/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**6 + 20*ba**4*r2**6/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**6 - 32*ba**3*r1**5/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**5 - 32*ba**3*r2**5/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**5 + 12*ba**2*r1**4/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**4 + 12*ba**2*r2**4/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**4) + 1.0*c9*da**2*r12**2*(6*ba**2*r1**4/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**4 + 6*ba**2*r2**4/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**4 - 8*ba*r1**3/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**3 - 8*ba*r2**3/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**3 + 2*r1**2/(ba*r1 + 1.0)**2 + 2*r2**2/(ba*r2 + 1.0)**2)/(da*r12 + 1.0)**2)
```

I guess it would be equally useful if I could use the `**` operator for power in C++, but I don’t know if this is even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your target is C++ code, the designated method is `sympy.printing.ccode`, which should take care of anything specific to C (and thus C++) and has further features that might be useful to you:

```py
from sympy.printing import ccode
from sympy import a,b,c
expression = a**b+c**a-b**c**a
print(ccode(expression)) # 'pow(a, b) - pow(b, pow(c, a)) + pow(c, a)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing `sympy.Expr` objects is delegated to `sympy.printing.sstr`, which in turn is a small wrapper that uses `sympy.printing.StrPrinter`.

You can thus monkeypatch `sympy.printing.StrPrinter._print_Pow` to generate a `pow(x, y)` string instead of `x**y`.